# Finding polynomial functions that satisfy a given condition

Tags: functions, polynomials

> Find all polynomial functions $P(x)$ which satisfy $P(x)^2=P(P(x))$.

Attempt at reaching answer:

Let $d$ be the degree of $p(x) $.

We have $d+d=d*d \implies d=0 \vee d=2$.

If $d=0$ we have that $p(x)$ is constant, and this is indeed a solution.

Otherwise, we have $d=2 \implies p(x)=ax^2+bx+c$.

Plugging this into the original equation, we get
$(ax^2+bx+c)^2=a(ax^2+bx+c)^2+b(ax^2+bx+c)+c$.

Checking the coefficient of $x^4$ gives trivially $a=1$.

Rewriting and simplifying gives
$bx^2+b^2x+bc+c=0 \forall x \implies b=0 $ , $ c=0$.

Hence our solutions are
$p(x) = x $ and $p(x)= c$, with $c \in \mathbb{R} $.

Apparently, the first function (p(x)=x) is correct, but the second one isn't because it's not a *polynomial function* and it doesn't work for $x^2+1$... What would the correct answer then be?

Comment: Should be $p(x)=x^2$, not $p(x)=x$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may proceed as follows:

Differentiating gives
$$2P(x)P'(x) = P'(P(x))P'(x)$$

Obviously the identity is satisfied, if $P'(x) = 0 \Rightarrow P(x) = c \stackrel{c^2=c}{\Longrightarrow} c=0$ or $c=1$ .

Now, if $P'(x) \neq 0$, then setting $y=P(x)$ gives us on a non-empty open interval the polynomial equation
$$2y = \frac{dP}{dy} \Rightarrow P(y) = y^2+d$$

Plugging this into the original identity gives 
$$(y^2+d)^2 \stackrel{!}{=}(y^2+d)^2 + d \Leftrightarrow d=0$$

So, the possible polynomials are $P(x) =x^2$, $P(x) =1$, and $P(x) =0$.

Comment: How did you get $P(y)=y^2+d$  in the second equation? Also, what does 'd' represent in the second and third equations? Does it just mean any constant? Also, in the third equation, why is it $(y^2+d)^2+d$; how did you get $+d$?

Comment: @AlexanderB : If the derivative $P'(y)$ of a polynomial $P(y)$ is $2y$, then the original polynomial must be of the form $P(y) = y^2+d$, where $d$ is a constant. I used $d$ as a constant instead of $c$, since $c$ was already used in the step before.

Now it remains to be checked, whether $P(y)^2 =P(P(y))$:  On the RHS we get $P(P(y)) = P(y^2+d) = (y^2+d)^2+d$.

Answer (score 2):

When $p(x)=c$  you need $c^{2}=c$ so $c=0$ or $c=1$.

$p(x)=x$ is not a solution. You should get $p(x)=x^{2}$.

So the answer is $p(x)=x^{2}$ or $p(x)=0$ or $p(x)=1$. It is wrong to say that a constant is not a polynomial.

Comment: You are right, I relied on what OP said, I have now corrected the answer.

Comment: Did you get to your answer by differentiating too?

Comment: You can also get the solution by differentiation.